# I am not the shape I am

Tags: riddle

> When I'm in love, I like to skip out of joy. 
>  When I'm in
>   trouble, things can get real shocking.
>
> You will be sad when I'm broken,
>  but don't worry I can take quite
>   the beating.
>
> People will tell you to listen to me,
>  but only smart people will
>   know what to listen for.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are:

> A heart

When I'm in love, I like to skip out of joy.

> Your heart "skips" when you're in love

When I'm in trouble, things can get real shocking.

> If you have a heart problem, you may need a "shock" from a defibrillator.

You will be sad when I'm broken

> Figuratively, a "broken heart" means you are saddened.

but don't worry I can take quite the beating.

> Your physical heart "beats"

People will tell you to listen to me

> "Listen to your heart" is an idiom meaning listen to your inner voice.

but only smart people will know what to listen for.

> Well-educated Doctors know how to listen to a physical heart.

And your title: "I am not the shape I am"

> The real human heart is not really the shape of the common symbol used to represent it.

Comment: Spot on! I guess this one was _heartly_ a challenge. Good job _beating_ it

Comment: @SirDuckduck Easy riddles are sometimes just as fun as tough ones. Thanks for your hard work.

Comment: Was about to suggest the answer was Pickachu.. :-D

Comment: since it skips around, shocks when in danger and is a god damn TANK in the anime.

Comment: @Stender hahaha